# How to assign dataGrid to other dataGrid in Flex. a = b doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, object, datagrid

in Flex I have something like that:

```
  var dg:DataGrid = new DataGrid();    
  if (something) dg = dg1 else if (something_2) dg = dg2;
  dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(3).id;
```

and `dg` is ALWAYS pointing at `DataGrid` (even if `dg1` has name `DataGrid_test` and `dg2 = DataGrid_test2`) and finally action is made on my first `DataGrid` (`DataGrid_test`).
Why?
How can I pass `dg1` or `dg2` to `dg`?

Here is pasted almost full code of this part of application. I edited it to make that more clear.

```
    var dg:DataGrid = null; 
    if ( currentState == "state1" ) { //if this condition is true then app. go into if and
        dg = dataGrid_first; // make dg = DataGrid (1)
        test.text = "inco";  // shows "inco" in "test" label
    } else if ( currentState == "state2" ) { // if this is true then app. go..
        dg = dataGrid_second; //here and set dg as DataGrid (exactly!) (2)
        test.text = "outgo"; // and change test label into blank text (earlier text disapears)
    }
    search(dg);
```

It is modified with advice of '@splash'
Still not working.

EDIT:
I made this sceond edit to answer for all You who are helping me with that :) I think that it will be the best way. In codeblock above I added comments. (please read now comments and after that come back here :) )
Now I will explain exactly what happens. 
I debug it many times and here are results:
dg is pointing at DataGrid (as component in flex, not as my dataGrid_first), I needed to extend DataGrid so now it is ColorColumn component (I don't know if I called it properly), not DataGrid. And dg is pointing at ColorColumn not at dataGrid_first or dataGrid_second. I even tried today the same thing what suggest @splash:

```
if ( currentState == "state1" ) { 
    test.text = "inco"; 
    search(dataGrid_first); 
} else if ( currentState == "state2" ) {
    test.text = "outgo";
    search(dataGrid_second);
}
```

and search still points at ColorColumn :/ My problem is really easy- I just want to pass to search different dataGrid on each state. If You have other ideas how I can do that in right way then I will pleased to hear about it. :)
But still I don't understand why it doesn't work. My search function uses algorhitm Boyer-Moor for searching through dataGrid.dataProvider for some text. If it find something then it is pushed into new array and after passing whole dataProvider I colorize rows with searched word.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking.  Of course it's pointing to 'DataGrid' that's the class... Also, I don't understand your 'logic'.  Why would you ever create a DataGrid if you're just going to switch it anyways? Extremely convoluted code..

Comment: I write an application which has 2 different DataGrid's in states. In first state DataGrid has id= "dg1" in second id="dg2". I have also button which has an action "Search". That button is in both states. Now I try to do action that pressing "Search" in first state pass to search function dg1, pressing Search in second state passing dg2. It's  easy, I'm sure, but I'm missing something... :/ You wrote: "Why would you ever create a DataGrid if you're just going to switch it anyways?". What better way You suggest to do that?

Comment: I would love to suggest better, but I can't suggest on a technical question like that.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I answer similar question after this post so I will past it here to:  I want do that search function searches through different dataGrid.dataProvider in different states. In state1 search function should search for text in dg1 and in state2 search function should search in dg2.

Comment: But why do you need states? What are the search for?  Why are there 2?

Comment: 1. I need states because in 'state1' I have incomes and in 'state2' I have outgo. 2. Search is for searching income/outgo 'tables' for name of typed text (e.g. I have 100 different incomes in dataGrid and I want to search for that which have in name 'books'. I type in search input, press search button and that will fire search function. In state1 it should search through dataGrid_first.dataProvider in state2 it should search in dataGrid_second.dataProv.. 3. there are even more states but I need search only in those 2 :)

Comment: Well, these are a few solutions here.  You can use states, but I don't think that's the best thing in this case.  If anything, just use a viewstack for it so you don't have to 'switch' dg vars around.  Keep it simple.  It might be a better option to have a search for each datagrid than to have 2 datagrids with one search.

Comment: I have some other states and some functionalities on that states too so I need to have it on different states. I also think that it is better way to have just one search function because it made exactly the same in both cases. Just dataGrid is changing. So if I will have 2 searches then it will be a lot of almost the same code.

Comment: Well, tell you the truth, I have a gut feeling (pun intended) that you're not architecting your application properly, or at least not splitting up large chunks into smaller bits to reduce complexity and increase reusability.  But again, I can't really comment since I still don't know the overall picture of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's hard to write about whole application. I'm sure that, like You wrote, I didn't build it very well because it's my first program in Flex. :) I'm still learning. So maybe let's focus now only on that fact- how can I achieve that search function will get data from dg1.dataProvider (it's Array) in state1 and in state2 search function will get data from dg2.dataProvider (also array). I've just tested it in different ways and find out that no matter what object I'll pass by this: search(income_arr) or search(income_dataGrid), search function gets class, not specific object...

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. It started to work! It looks like I've had invalidateDisplayList() in wrong place. I've added it to dataProvider, not to dataGrid. It is still a little strange why that worked in one state and in other not but I can figure it out by myself. Can I give You somehow points for helping me? It really helped me and I'm grateful for that.

Comment: Since invalidateDisplayList() is the actual problem, it was in fact a visualization problem, not an in-program data structure one. Please accept one or both answers.

Comment: I think that accepting one or both is not quite good idea because it can mislead other people who search the internet.  And I can accept only one. I want to give You "up" but I must earn 9 points more to be able do that. When I'll have 15 rank points then I will give all of You "up's" :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If `dg` is never pointing to `dg1` and `dg2` then your `(something)` expressions may be evaluate to `false`. Check the value of your if-conditions - this should be easy to debug.

This should work:

```
var dg:DataGrid = null;    
if (something) 
    dg = dg1;
else if (something_2) 
    dg = dg2;
if (dg)
{
    // do something with dg
}
```

**[Update]**

I still can't see why your code isn't working, but you could simplify it like this:

```
if ( currentState == "state1" ) { 
    test.text = "inco"; 
    search(dataGrid_first); 
} else if ( currentState == "state2" ) {
    test.text = "outgo";
    search(dataGrid_second);
}
```

Comment: I have something like that (now I pasted code from application, earlier I changed it to write it shorter).       'code'        var dg:DataGrid = null;    if ( currentState == "state1" ) {
  dg = dataGrid_first;
  test.text = "inco";
  
  
 } else if ( currentState == "state2" ) {
  dg = dataGrid_second;
  test.text = "outgo";
  
 }   'code'    In state1 everything is OK but still dg gets "DataGrid", not dataGrid_first. Even so that do what I want to do. Label "test" shows "inco" so if is good. In state2 nothing works. Nor dg gets dataGrid_second, nor "test" shows "outgo";

Comment: Thank You splash for helping me. :) In conversation with '@J_A_X' I wrote that I found a solution. I've just added incorrectly invalidateDisplayList() and that is why I thought that it doesn't work. It doesn't colorize rows which were result of actions done by this code. All of You 3 guys really helped me and I'm grateful for that. And unfortunatelly I haven't enough rank points for vote Your answer up. Thanks again for help, I'll try pay it forward on stackoverflow users :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to write this - since I guess either dg1 or dg2 should be assigned:

```
if (something) {

    dg = dg1;

} else {

    dg = dg2;

}
```

There may be cases, where if () {} else () {} neither executes the first or the second conditional block.

Finally a small hint, which structurally eliminates unwanted assignments in if conditions: Always write the literal left of the comparison operation: `if ( "state1" == currentState  )`. If you accidentally typed `=` instead of `==`, the flex compiler emits an error. The other notation silently assigns a value.

Additionally: Did you single-stepped through your code and watched the variables dg1, dg2 and dg? If not, set a breakpoint a few line before the if-statement and run the code step by step from there on. What do you see?

Here's a another tip: Use assertions to check for inconistencies:

```
package my.company.utilities {

  public function assert(expression:Boolean):void {

      // probably conditionally compile this statement
      if (!expression) {
          throw new Error("Assertion failed!");
      }

  } // assert

}
```

Use it e.g. at the beginning of a method like this:

```
public function doTransaction( fromAccount:int, toAccount:int ) {

  assert( 0 < fromAccount );
  assert( 0 < toAccount );

}
```

A typically good use of assert is to check variables regarding their range. As of the above example, fromAccount and toAccount should always be positive. Due to a bug, bad values might get passed to doTransaction(). In this case, the assertion fires an error.

Comment: I must admit that Your suggest of 'if' statement is really interesting. I didn't see something like that earlier and I need to explore it deeper. You wrote that maybe if doesn't execute one of those if's but it does. In both if's I inserted something like that: 'test.text = "inco";' and in first if it works and in second it doesn't work. I think that the best way to write about that will be edit of my first post with formatted code and inserting some comments in it. Please look up on that page to my "post".

Comment: Yes, I'm writing about it now in first post but I need few minutes :) I'm still editing it

Comment: I do not fully understand, what you mean by 'set dg as DataGrid (exactly!)': DataGrid is a class, not an object. Thus, the type of dg might be DataGrid, but not the value.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity: Do you speak of a visual problem? Does the visual representation of dg does not change? Or do you technically speak of the in-program value?

Comment: I'm talking about in-program value. I want do that search function searches through different dataGrid.dataProvider in different states. In state1 search function should search for text in dg1 and in state2 search function should search in dg2.

Comment: Maybe You red my comments in conversation with '@J_A_X' so You probably now that problem was in quite another place. You suggested me to debug it precisely so I finally did breakpoints almost in each line and figure out that everything is OK. I just didn't add invalidateDisplayList() correctly so in view rows weren't colorized. I will give You "arrow up" ("this answer is useful") because You (well, all of You who wrote in this "topic") really helped me by different ideas of solution :)

Comment: Oh, and also thank You for assertions. I was wondering earlier about it how can I do something similar so in future I will use it.comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss). P.S-unfortunatelly I can't vote this up because I don't have enough rank points. :/